# Newshape parameter in numpy.reshape can be a list?

Tags: numpy, reshape

The numpy official document specifies the synopsis of `reshape` as follows:

`numpy.reshape(a, newshape, order='C')`
where `newshape` can be an int or tuple of ints.

The document does not say `newshape` can be a list, but my testing indicates that `newshape` can be a list. For example:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
b = a.reshape([3,2])
>>> b
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```

Is the feature of providing `newshape` as a list a nonstandard extension, so that the document does not mention it?

Comment: Tuples and lists have similar properties, and often you can use arraylike objects like list, tuple, set or numpy array interchangeably. They don't write about all possibilities.

Comment: It may be worth to specify all possibilities. For example, `isinstance(3,(int,float))` works, but `isinstance(3,[int,float])` does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Tuples and lists have similar properties, and often you can use arraylike objects (or iterables) like lists, tuples, sets, or NumPy arrays interchangeably. They don't write in the documentation about all possibilities. I guess they use tuple in this case because if you call the function `shape` it returns a tuple of ints.